The $p$-adic valuation of a linear recurrence sequence
Let $a$ be the sequence of integers (already mentioned here), defined by
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(a_0, a_1) = (1, 8) \\
a_{n+2} = 6a_{n+1} - a_n
\end{array}
\right.$$
I wonder which prime numbers $p$ are such that $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \nu_p(a_n) = +\infty$, where $\nu_p$ denotes the $p$-adic valuation.
It is not enough for $p$ to divide one of the terms of the sequence $a$: indeed $13 \mid a_5$ but no term of the sequence $a$ is divisible by $13^2$.
Unless I am mistaken, I have proven here that $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \nu_2(a_n) = +\infty$
And for example, a computational investigation leads me to think that $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \nu_{19}(a_n) = +\infty$.
I have indicated in the table below, for the first values of $k$, the smallest natural number $n$ such that $19^k \mid a_n$:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
k & n \\
\hline
1 & 7 \\
\hline
2 & 67 \\
\hline
3 & 447 \\
\hline
4 & 58207 \\
\hline
5 & 812697 \\
\hline
6 & 20360847 \\
\hline
7 & 193687777 \\
\hline
8 & 2075523017 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Nice question! The following is not a complete answer. First, $a_n$ has closed form $a_n = c \alpha^n + d \beta^n$ for some constants $c, d$ where
$$\alpha = 3 + 2 \sqrt{2}, \beta = 3 - 2 \sqrt{2}$$
are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $t^2 - 6t + 1$. The initial conditions give $c + d = 1, c \alpha + d \beta = 8$, and solving for $c, d$ gives $c = \frac{4 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{8}, d = \frac{4 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{8}$, so
$$a_n = \frac{4 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{8} (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^n + \frac{4 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{8} (3 - 2 \sqrt{2})^n.$$
Next we work $p$-adically, doing the same calculations but in the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Depending on the value of $p$, either $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\sqrt{2}$ lives in a quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2})$ (which when $p = 2$ is ramified), and the above closed form continues to be valid in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2})$. We want to understand when it is possible for the $p$-adic absolute value $|a_n|_p = p^{-\nu_p(a_n)}$ to get arbitrarily small in terms of this closed form.
If the quadratic extension is nontrivial, the $p$-adic absolute value extends to $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2})$ via $|\alpha|_p = \sqrt{N(\alpha)_p}$ where $N : \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ is the norm. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both have norm $1$, so $|\alpha|_p = |\beta|_p = 1$. That means we can divide by $\beta^n$ without affecting the absolute value, so the problem is equivalent to understanding when
$$b_n = \left( \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \right)^n = \alpha^{2n} = (17 + 12 \sqrt{2})^n$$
gets arbitrarily close to
$$- \frac{d}{c} = \frac{-4 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{4 + 5 \sqrt{2}} = \frac{33 - 20 \sqrt{2}}{17}$$
(which also has norm $1$). If $p \neq 2, 17$ then all of the above calculations happen in $\mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{2}]$ and can be reduced $\bmod p$ (in particular $c, d$ are invertible $\bmod p$ and we work in either $\mathbb{F}_p$ or the unique quadratic extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$), and a necessary condition for $\alpha^{2n}$ to get arbitrarily close to $- \frac{d}{c}$ is that there exists some $n$ such that their difference is divisible by $p$, hence such that
$$\alpha^{2n} \equiv - \frac{d}{c} \bmod p$$
has a solution. I have no idea how to determine which primes $p$ have this property; this seems potentially as hard as Artin's primitive root conjecture.
So, let's just assume that a solution exists $\bmod p$. Then we only want to consider $n$ satisfying $\alpha^{2n} \equiv - \frac{d}{c} \bmod p$; these have the form $n = n_0 + e m$ where $n_0$ is the smallest solution and $e$ is the order of $\alpha^2 \bmod p$ (again, $\bmod p$ here means working in either $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, so this order divides $p^2 - 1$). Popping back up to $\mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{2}]$ this means we want to solve
$$(\alpha^{2e})^m \approx - \frac{d}{c} \alpha^{-2n_0}$$
for $m$ (where $\approx$ means $p$-adically close). Here, importantly, both the RHS and $\alpha^{2e}$ are now $1 \bmod p$. This means (for $p \neq 2$) that we can now apply the $p$-adic logarithm, which is a continuous isomorphism $(1 + p \mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{2}], \times) \cong (p \mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{2}], +)$, to get that this condition is equivalent to
$$m \log \alpha^{2e} \approx \log \left( - \frac{d}{c} \alpha^{2n_0} \right) \in p \mathbb{Z}_p[\sqrt{2}].$$
This makes it clearer what is happening: we can get arbitrarily close $p$-adically iff the logarithm on the RHS is divisible by the logarithm on the LHS, or equivalently iff the "base $\alpha^{2e}$ logarithm" $\log_{\alpha^{2e}} \left( - \frac{d}{c} \alpha^{-2n_0} \right)$ exists, and is furthermore an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$; if so, this logarithm is an element $m_{\infty} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ which satisfies
$$\alpha^{2n_0 + 2em_{\infty}} = - \frac{d}{c}$$
exactly, and we get integers getting arbitrarily close by truncating it. On the other hand, if $m_{\infty}$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ then we can't approximate it arbitrarily closely by integers.
This is what's happening in your $p = 19$ example, and in particular why all the values of $n$ end in $7$: $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 19$ so the calculations $\bmod p$ take place in $\mathbb{F}_{19^2}$, so the fact that all your values of $n$ agree $\bmod 10$ indicates that the order of $\alpha^2 \in \mathbb{F}_{19^2}$ is $10$ (which can also be verified by checking that the order of $a_n \bmod 19$ is $20$), so we get $e = 10$ in the above (and $n_0 = 7$). Your values of $n$ are converging to an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{19}$. Here's a table of the corresponding values of $m$ and their base-$19$ expansions so we can see this more clearly:



$k$
$m = \frac{n-7}{10}$
base-$19$




$1$
$0$
$0_{19}$


$2$
$6$
$6_{19}$


$3$
$44$
$26_{19}$


$4$
$5820$
$g26_{19}$


$5$
$812\color{red}{69}$
$bg26_{19}$


$6$
$2036084$
$fbg26_{19}$


$7$
$19638777$
$7fbg26_{19}$


$8$
$207752301$
$47fbg26_{19}$



As you can see we gain exactly one digit each time; these are exactly the truncations of some $19$-adic number $m_{\infty} = \dots 47fbg26_{19}$. This calculation even reveals that your table has a typo ($812\color{red}{96}$ breaks the pattern).

The above analysis suggests that the issue with $p = 13$ is that in this case the $p$-adic logarithm $\log \alpha^{2e}$ is divisible by $13^2$ but the $p$-adic logarithm $\log \left( - \frac{d}{c} \alpha^{-2n_0} \right)$ is not. Let's see if we can verify this. $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 13$ so the calculation $\bmod 13$ takes place in $\mathbb{F}_{13^2}$. The first term divisible by $13$ is $a_6$, which gives $n_0 = 6$. The sequence $a_n \bmod 13$ has an eventual period of $14$, which implies (this requires a small argument) that the order of $\alpha \bmod 13$ is $14$, and hence that the order of $\alpha^2 \bmod 13$ is $7$, so $e = 7$. But $a_n \bmod 13^2$ also has period $14$ and there are no terms divisible by $13^2$; this means the order of $\alpha^2 \bmod 13^2$ must also be $7$, which can be verified by an explicit calculation, which means exactly that $\alpha^{14} \equiv 1 \bmod 13^2$ and hence that its logarithm is divisible by $13^2$. On the other hand we should be able to check that $- \frac{d}{c} \alpha^{-12}$ is not congruent to $1 \bmod 13^2$, so its logarithm is not divisible by $13^2$.

I am not very familiar with the $p$-adic logarithm, especially not on extensions of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so if anyone more familiar with these issues could double-check my arguments using it I would very much appreciate that.

I must admit that I do not possess the necessary skills to appreciate your contribution. Thank you for pointing out the typo, I have corrected it.

Two articles among others that deal with this kind of question : C. Sanna, “The p-adic valuation of Lucas sequences”, Fibonacci Q. 54 (2016), p. 118-224. and T. Lengyel, The order of the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, The Fibonacci Quarterly, 33.3 (1995), 234–239.

@uvdose: those are nice results. The Fibonacci case is easier because in that case $- \frac{d}{c} = 1$ so we don't have to worry about whether $n_0$ exists, it just always exists. For the Lucas numbers $- \frac{d}{c} = -1$ which is the next easiest case. Here we have to work harder. But the general idea of working $p$-adically should apply to all second-order recurrences. For third-order and higher recurrences we can't reduce to understanding powers of a single element like this, sadly, and I guess we have to analyze a $p$-adic matrix.
